# Pandas change muliindex to index and multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this

```
| Feature | Channel | Value |
|---------|---------|-------|
| a       | 0       | 1.3   |
|         | 1       | 1.3   |
|         | 2       | 1.3   |
| b       | 0       | 1.2   |
|         | 1       | 1.2   |
|         | 2       | 1.2   |
```

where `Feature` and `Channel` are a multiindex

how can I turn this into the following:

```
| channel | a   | b   |
|---------|-----|-----|
| 0       | 1.3 | 1.2 |
| 1       | 1.3 | 1.2 |
| 2       | 1.3 | 1.2 |
```

where channel is now the index, and a and b are separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
new_df = df.unstack(level=0)
```

`new_df`:

```
        Value     
Feature     a    b
Channel           
0         1.3  1.2
1         1.3  1.2
2         1.3  1.2
```

---

With [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) + [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
new_df = df.unstack(0).droplevel(0, 1).rename_axis(columns=None)
```

`new_df`:

```
           a    b
Channel          
0        1.3  1.2
1        1.3  1.2
2        1.3  1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot might be easier (drop the index first) -

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.pivot(index='Channel',columns='Feature',values='Value')
```

Comment: Yep, you beat me to my edit, revised to show reset_index first.